# Ajax function being set in controller but returning null reference

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

At work I have to set two functions a certain way. Below is the function:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '<%:ViewData("WhiteMillsURL").ToString%>ApprovalCenter/ForwardApprovalsMulti',
             dataType: 'jsonp',
             data: {
                 lanid: '<%: CMMS.Core.CMMSGlobals.CMMSApp.CurrentUser.lanid %>',
                redirectuser: $("#redirectuser").val(),
                approvaltype: $("#approvaltype").val(),
                todate: $("#todate").val()
            },
             crossDomain: true,
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#statuses").append('<li>White Mills : ' + data.data + '</li>');
                 $("#statuses").listview('refresh');
             }
        });
```

now I set this in the controller as so:

```
 Function ForwardMultiMill() As ActionResult
        If Not Authentication.Authentication.AuthenticateUser() Then Return Nothing
        Dim rewriter = New RewriteService.URLRewriterClient
        ViewData("ValdostaURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//valcmmsweb.pca.com/")
        ViewData("CounceURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//coucmmsweb.pca.com/")
        ViewData("TomahawkURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//tomcmmsweb.pca.com/")
        ViewData("FilerURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//filcmmsweb.pca.com/")
        ViewData("WhiteMillsURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//m-valcmmsweb.pca.com/")
        ViewData("ValdostaAPIURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//tridentval.pca.com/api/Core/")
        ViewData("DeRidderAPIURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//tridentder.pca.com/api/Core/")
        ' ViewData("DeridderAPIURL") = rewriter.RewriteURL(Request.UserHostAddress(), "//localhost:61881/api/Core/")
        Return View()
    End Function
```

but it returns:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by usercode.
>   An Exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' Occurred in App_Web_tvahwyu5.dll but was not handled in user code.

I am an intern and I asked our main web developer and he said I had to set it in the controller which I thought I did. the Deridder ajax function looks the same and is set the same and works. This makes me think it is set somewhere else. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Get this also, there was a reference to `System.Web.MVC` that I fixed a while ago don't know how that affects this though.

[image]

here is when I hover over the break point
[image]

Comment: Did you check with a break point in controller what value is assigned to `ViewData("WhiteMillsURL") ` ? Also `.ToString()` is a function and should have brackets followed, isn't it?

Comment: @SivaGopal, it should have `()`, but VB is quite forgiving.

Comment: @SivaGopal What's the point in doing that? Did you see the screenshot of the error? It's a null reference, so `ViewData("WhiteMillsURL")` is null and the breakpoint will only show what you already know.

Comment: @RacilHilan That is the point I want OP to verify so that he can get some alternative. By debugging he can gather more accurate details, like: if value is set properly and not null in controller but still null reference in View may be because, there could be some space before/after key, or incorrect casings of key in question etc. Isn't it?

Comment: @InbetweenWeekends Thanks for pointing that. Always C# in eyes.. :)

Comment: I added a pic but the ones that work have same stuff in it

Comment: SO.... update. I deleted the bin and obj folder and that part works now but the now a different part that used to work is now having that same null error when i know for a fact it works.